# Rails 3.2 app on Ubuntu 10.04 with Plesk 11, nginx as reverse proxy and apache

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, nginx, unicorn, plesk

i have a Virtual Server with Ubuntu 10.04 from Hosteurope.
Plesk 11.0.9 is installed.
nginx as a reverse proxy activated.

On my local Ubuntu installation i installed a rails app with :
rvm, ruby 1.9.3, rails 3.2.10, nginx, unicorn. everything is working fine.

My question, is there a chance to install a rails app with nginx and unicorn on Plesk 11?

Anyone successfully managed this?

Or is there a better way to run a rails app on Ubuntu with Plesk 11?

thanks

Answer (score 0):

**UPDATE:**
Ok, I was able to get this going with both nginx + thin and nginx + passenger. Here's the steps to get started (Plesk 11):

1. Stop nginx in Plesk (Tools & Settings => Services Management)
2. Uninstall Plesk's nginx from the command line via: yum remove sw-nginx
3. Install nginx from source or via their RPM

I'm trying to tackle this right now and from what I can tell Plesk uses nginx as a reverse proxy and is doing a lot of weird things with the nginx config. I haven't been able to get it working using nginx + Thin. I am also trying apache + passenger or nginx + passenger.

I don't have a definitive answer but it appears to be not possible (with nginx at least).